# test nodatabase ajax rails form calculator with rspec&co

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rspec, capybara

I have ajax rails NoDatabase form calculator. It works well, but I want to test it properly.  I test it with rspec and capybara. All tests pass when it was simple ruby/rails implementation. When I add ajax, all tests fails.
What technique should I use to test it with ajax?

InterestCalculator controller:

```
class InterestCalculatorController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @result_0 = 0
  end

  def new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render 'index.html.erb' }
      format.js
    end 

    # If accepted parameter is integer, then it shows in view as 5, when it
    # is float, it shows as 5.1  
    @first_0   = params[:a_0].to_f % 1 != 0 ? params[:a_0].to_f : params[:a_0].to_i
    @second_0  = params[:b_0].to_f % 1 != 0 ? params[:b_0].to_f : params[:b_0].to_i

    # How many percent is number from the number 
    number_to_number(@first_0, @second_0) 

  end

 private 

   def number_to_number(a = 0, b = 0)   
    # If the first number is zero, it sends 0% answer. If the second number is zero 
    # and the first number is nonzero, it sends infinity. Otherwise simple formula calculation.
    if a.zero?
      @result_0 = 0
    elsif b.zero?
      @result_0 = "infinity"
    else
      @result_0 = a.to_f / b.to_f * 100
    end 
  end
end
```

My view index.html.erb

```
  <div id="interest_calculator">
    <%= form_for :interest_calculator, url: { action: :new }, method: :get, remote: true do |f|   %>
      <p>Сколько % составляет число</p>
      <%= number_field_tag :a_0, params[:a_0], step: :any, id: "first_number_0" %>
      <p>от числа</p>
      <%= number_field_tag :b_0, params[:b_0], step: :any, id: "second_number_0" %>
      <%= f.submit 'Calculate!', id: "number_to_number" %>
    <% end %>

    <% unless @result_0.nil? %>
      <p>Number <span id="first_0"><%= @first_0 %></span> from number <span id="second_0"><%= @second_0 %></span> = <label id="answer_0"></label>%</p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

My new.js.erb

```
document.getElementById("answer_0").innerHTML = "<%= @result_0 %>"
document.getElementById("first_0").innerHTML = "<%= @first_0 %>"
document.getElementById("second_0").innerHTML = "<%= @second_0 %>"
```

simple no ajax test:

```
  scenario 'persent at number to number' do   
    visit interest_calculator_index_path
    expect(page).to have_content('Interest Calculator')
    fill_in "a_0", with: 5
    fill_in "b_0", with: 5
    click_button("number_to_number")
    expect(page).to have_css("#answer_0", text: "100.0%")
  end
```

failing test output:

```
  5) interest calculator test persent at number to number
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_css("#answer_0", text: "100.0%")
       expected to find css "#answer_0" with text "100.0%" but there were no matches
     # ./spec/features/interest_calculator_number_to_number_spec.rb:38:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Give an example of "fails", the test, the error you get, etc.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole done

Comment: Which JS capable driver are you using? See https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/README.md#selecting-the-driver. (And FYI it's spelled "percent" not persent)

Comment: @ThomasWalpole thanks for typo correction.   I use   
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Issue with selenium - it doesn't work without mozilla geckodriver. And for example, if I want to test my app in another working station, i must install this geckodriver. I want to implement my testing without 3-rd party.

Comment: You can't if you need JS support,  The selenium driver needs geckodriver (for FF) or chromedriver (for Chrome), poltergeist needs phantomjs, and capybara-webKit needs Qt in order to build.  You can find gems that will manage downloading the latest geckdriver, etc. but you can't test JS without somehow installing one of them